# Retrieve num rows of data between 1 to 31 of a month in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch the data that was created between a specific month, for example I am trying to get the total number of rows of data created in December 2019.

here is my model code

```
//Get january sles
public function getJanSale()
{
    $yr = date('Y');
    $this->db->where('td_created_at BETWEEN "'. date('d-m-Y', strtotime("1-12-".$yr)). '" and "'. date('d-m-Y', strtotime("31-12-".$yr)).'"');
    $query = $this->db->get('zd_item_downloads');
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

And as result is returned 0. Meanwhile I got some data created in December which insert as current timestamp in my database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code, here

```
    public function getJanSale()
    {
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $this->db->where('MONTH(td_created_at) = '. $month. ' AND YEAR(td_created_at) = '. $year);
        $query = $this->db->get('zd_item_downloads');
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

Or more simple with Mysql function `CURDATE()`

```
    $this->db->where('MONTH(td_created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(td_created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code, here

```
    public function getSale()
    {
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $this->db->where('MONTH(td_created_at) = '. $month. ' AND YEAR(td_created_at) = '. $year);
        $query = $this->db->get('zd_item_downloads');
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For all month total :**

```
select
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov',
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec'
from 
  zd_item_downloads
```

**For single month :**

```
select
  SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec'
from 
  zd_item_downloads
```

**Updating as per the year total count**

```
$this->db->select("
  SUM(CASE year(td_created_at) WHEN " . date("Y") . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'current_year_total'")
->from('zd_item_downloads')
```

Manage php date("y") function to get previous year count

**For specific dec 2019**

```
$this->db->select("
      SUM(CASE month(td_created_at) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec'")
->from('zd_item_downloads')
->where("td_created_at BETWEEN '" . date("Y") . "/01/01' AND '" . date("Y") . "/12/31'")
```

Comment: I wish to get base on yearly basis

Comment: Yes sir  for example I want to show sale of Dec 2019 so when d year cahbgrs to Dec 2020 I get base on that actual year

Comment: @Zubdev
updated the answer as per both the scenarios

Comment: your answer is not appropriate

Comment: Can you please explain your statement.
As your ans is not correct as per the result what @Zubdev want. your query will provide unnecessary all row with all column and mine just return one row with one count column